# How to parallelize python nested loops?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, neural-network

i'm computing this function that calculates the wasserstein_distance using Scipy. The problem is that data[row][column] can be very big (from approx. 60k values until 300k) and it takes so much time to elaborate. Is there a way to parallelize it in order to "assign" to each processor of the machine a specific range of elements to elaborate^ I.e.: first processor can elaborate the distance between the first 24 pixels (0,0) and all the others (0,0) to (23,23), second processor the distance between the next 24 pixels (from (1,0) to (1,23)) and all the others (0,0) to (23,23). Any other suggestions are welcome :

```
def compute_wasserstein_distances(tflite, data, rows, columns, output_filename):

    # Initialize an empty dictionary to store wasserstein distances
    dist_similarity = {}
    
    # Iterate through rows and columns of the grid
    for row in tqdm(range(0, rows)):              
        for column in tqdm(range(0, columns), leave= False):
            for r in range(0, rows):
                for c in range(0, columns):
                    # Calculate the Wasserstein distance between the distributions
                    distance = wasserstein_distance(data[row][column], data[r][c])
                    
                    # Store the distance in the dictionary with corresponding indices
                    dist_similarity[((row, column), (r, c))] = distance

    print(f"[INFO] Saving pixel distribution to file ...")
    
    # Save the dist_similarity dictionary to a pickle file
    with open(f'{output_filename}/{tflite}-DistSimilarity.pkl', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(dist_similarity, file)
    
    return dist_similarity
```

I've tried to do this, but this for loop (for future in tqdm(futures)) takes too long.

```
import pickle
import concurrent.futures
from tqdm import tqdm
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance

def calculate_distance(row, column, r, c, data):
    return ((row, column), (r, c), wasserstein_distance(data[row][column], data[r][c]))

def compute_wasserstein_distances_parallel(tflite, data, rows, columns, output_filename):
    # Initialize an empty dictionary to store Wasserstein distances
    dist_similarity = {}

    # Create a ThreadPoolExecutor
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []

        # Iterate through rows and columns of the grid
        for row in tqdm(range(rows)):
            for column in tqdm(range(columns), leave=False):
                for r in range(rows):
                    for c in range(columns):
                        # Submit the task to the executor
                        futures.append(executor.submit(calculate_distance, row, column, r, c, data))

        # Wait for all tasks to complete
        concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

        # Retrieve results from futures
        for future in tqdm(futures):
            indices, distance = future.result()[:2], future.result()[2]
            dist_similarity[indices] = distance

    print(f"[INFO] Saving pixel distribution to file ...")

    # Save the dist_similarity dictionary to a pickle file
    with open(f'{output_filename}/{tflite}-DistSimilarity.pkl', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(dist_similarity, file)

    return dist_similarity
```

Comment: What do you mean that for loop takes too long? You have a parallel and a non-parallel version. What're you looking for?

Comment: The parallel version takes too much time to elaborate the (for future in tqdm(futures):), the non parallel version can executes up to 30hours. So, i'm trying to find an optimized version of my code, even parallelized, that can decrese computation times.

Comment: Try the ProcessPoolExecutor.

Comment: To expand on that recommendation, the ThreadPoolExecutor runs all of the parallel threads on the same processor.  This is useful when the subtasks are spending most of their time waiting (typically for IO).  To make use of multiple processors you need to use the ProcessPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ProcessPooolExecutor.  For CPU bound processes, like this, you need that to run on different CPU cores.

The ThreadPoolExecutor, runs on a single processor.  It is primarily useful for subprocesses that spend most of their time waiting, e.g. IO bound processes.

And, of course, you need to specify `max_workers=something` when creating the Executor, otherwise the default is 1.  Specifying this even on the ThreadPoolExecutor would improve your performance.

ProcessPooolExecutor has exactly the same interface as ThreadPoolExecutor.  So, to use, just replace

```
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
```

with

```
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_processors_to_use) as executor:
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the implementation using ProcessPooolExecutor? How to implement correctly this kind of parallelization?

Comment: Was my edit of my answer with more details adequate?